# VS2008 ClickOnce Publishing now failing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce

All of the sudden ClickOnce publishing has stopped working in Visual Studio 2008.

I am getting this error....

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [1/15/2014 12:14:43 PM] System.ArgumentException
    - Value does not fall within the expected range.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

I have tried to upgrade the application to VS2012 and deploy there but am getting the same error.

Note system changes since this last worked.

```
- Installed VS2012 Pro
- Installed VS2013 RC
- Upgraded IE 9 to IE10 and IE11, had no choice.
```

**IE 11 says that it can not access the setup.exe file of the web site to execute the OneClick install.**

```
- Installed VS2013Express without removing VS2013RC
- Misc. other MS updates.

- Removed VS2010Express
```

Checked IIS (ver6) still set to serve executable files.